# In unity C# script why Input is not exist?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (
        }
    }
```

Inside the if ( i type Input but it's not exist.
I tried to add in the top using.System.Io; but that's not the solution.

In my unity project i clicked in the menu on Assests > open C# Project and it opened a new mono develop scripting window.

In my unity project i have a firstpersoncharacter and under in it a spotlight.
I want to make in the script a key trigger like if i click on the key F it will turn on the spotlight and if i click on F again it will turn the spotlight off.

Comment: Found it i needed to drag the c# script icon to the spotlight object.

Comment: But still got some problems with the scripting. To edit my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

if there is no input you should check script:

1.fix compiler errors

2.if you haven't libraries you can not access to input or etc?

**using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;**

3.if you can't access to input you should install new monodevelop version from [monodevelop.com](http://monodevelop.com)

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

    public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool mybool;
    void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    GetComponent<Light> ().enabled = !mybool;
        }
}
```

explain:

!false = true

!true = false